# Can a script call msg.sender.send on any address with any amount?

Tags: contract-development

Just watched this tutorial (you can skip to 18:33 and pause to see what I'm referring to): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seU7DykOxfc

[image]

So it looks like the magical `msg` object is available in all the public methods of smart contracts. I noticed that `msg.sender` points to the address of 1) "self" when being called in a constructor and 2) the "other party" a.k.a. the method caller (another contract) when being called from a public method.

As you can see from the screenshot, the contract has a pointer to the `buyer` and it calls `buyer.send(value)`. Technically can't it just call that until the buyer has no more money / ether? What's stopping this contract from just calling it with arbitrary numbers and then running away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no it this call "self" when called in constructor it references the address of the person deploying the contract, the "this" keyword is what refrences self.

buyer.send() isnt deducting from the buyer address but on the contrary it is sending to eth to the buyer.

Comment: Oh but there's still a call to `sender.send(this.balance)`. So technically can't I just call `sender.send(9999999)`?

Comment: The `address.send()` function is confusing and should IMO be called `address.receive()` to make clear what it does. `sender.send(9999999)` sends 9999999 Wei from the contract's balance to the sender. If the contract doesn't have enough funds this fails.

Comment: o... but either way, lets say i'm the seller. can't i call seller.send(999) a lot of times and deduct a bunch of money from the buyer's account?

Comment: The money always comes out of the *contract*'s balance, so you can only send as much ETH as the contact poses

Comment: @TjadenHess is right.